# PHP: Simple PostgreSQL Query

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I am trying to realize a most simple way to query a postgreSQL db via a web site form. My current approach is the following, which results in a broken looking page (even the print command is ignored) and not reacting to submitting the values, i.e., not producing any output.
Could you give me a clue what is wrong with the code?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <title>Insert data to PostgreSQL with php - creating a simple web  application</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <style>
 li {listt-style: none;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>Enter Query</h2>
 <ul>
 <form name="insert" action="pg.html" method="POST" >
 <li>RA:</li><li><input type="text" name="ra" /></li>
 <li>Dec:</li><li><input type="text" name="dec" /></li>
 <li>Radius:</li><li><input type="text" name="radius" /></li>
 <li><input type="submit" /></li>
 </form>
 </ul>

 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "foo";
 $password = "bar";
 $dbname = "foobar";

 print "bla $dbname";

// Create connection
 $conn = pg_connect("host=$servername user=$username, password=$password dbname=$dbname");
// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE q3c_radial_query(RAJ2000, DECJ2000, ra, dec, radius)";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "RA: " . $row["RAJ2000"]. ", DEC: " . $row["DECJ2000"]. ", r" . $row["rmag"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
 $conn->close();
?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form's action points to `pg.html` so silly question: the file containing this code *is* a `.php` file, isn't it?

Comment: @Jakumi Could you elaborate on that? The query is taken from [here](https://github.com/segasai/q3c) and works if I run it separately.

Comment: @rickdenhaan It is a `.html` file since I read that php code can be included in html directly and `.php` can't be opened by Firefox. I am not a web developer, sorry about that.

Comment: sorry, didn't think that was a function. I hope you have installed that library?

Comment: Yes, PHP *code* can be included within HTML *code*, but you then have to rename the file to `.php` to tell your webserver to pass it through the PHP interpreter instead of serving it directly. Firefox will only have a problem with opening `.php` files if you open them locally by e.g. double-clicking it. PHP files need to be loaded through a webserver.

Comment: Side note : `listt-style` that's a typo, there's one "t" too much. `list-style`

Comment: @Jakumi Yes I have, up and running in psql.

Comment: You're also mixing different apis here. That's a major cause of why your code failed besides the `.html` thing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I took the first example from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) and changed it to postgres.

Comment: that's `mysqli_` you're using `pg_connect` to connect with http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php you need to use the same api from connection to querying.

Comment: @Fred-ii- From your link, I used the old `pg_connect syntax`, which should anyways be working, right?

Comment: if you're going to want to use the `mysqli_*` functions, you're going to have to connect with the same api http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php or vice-versa.

Comment: if you're going to want to use the postgreSQL api, you're going to have to use its related functions. Again, you can't mix different apis. Read the documentation for it and good luck.